# Remap Chromecast device button via ADB

Tags: adb, buttons, chromecast

I got a Chromecast with Google TV. It has the ability to emit certain infrared signals when a button on the remote is pressed, allowing the user to control both Chromecast and TV with one single remote.

However, my TV is not supported in the predefined mapping profiles, so I would like to be able to configure the remote to trigger custom infrared signals.

How can I do that via ADB? Something like `adb shell settings blah`.

Updates:

When running logcat, I notice these lines: `Axel.IrRemote: Uploading IR Profile '||1000024' to 60:98:66:D2:BF:E6`. So in the end it's basically just upload data via Bluetooth, so with the right information I guess it shall be possible to get the job done.

Comment: Just making sure that you know that IR code sets can be reused by multiple manufacturers so I would double check (and perhaps mention) your make/model of TV.

Comment: I use Kedro. I tried like 50 brands but none work. It's too tiring man, the finger, it hurts.